# can not connect to oracledb running in a docker container

Tags: oracle, macos, docker

Mac OS and docker 
From the oracledb console, I can not connect as sys, password I type in oracle and no go

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba;
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

how did I get this far...

```
    docker pull absolutapps/oracle-12c-ee
    docker run -d --name oracle-12cR1-ee --privileged absolutapps/oracle-12c-ee
    docker logs -f oracle-12cR1-ee
```

at then end of that I get

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Please login to http://<ip_address>:8080/em to use enterprise manager
User: sys; Password oracle; Sysdba: true
Fixing permissions...
Running init scripts...
Init scripts in /oracle.init.d/: Ignoring /oracle.init.d/*

Done with scripts we are ready to go
```

Next command I run is

```
docker exec -it 28b0f34f7a81 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Fri Jun 28 23:08:41 2019


Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys as sysdba;
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

at this point, I am stuck...

Thoughts or seen this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for that image you're using](https://github.com/padlik/oracle-12c/blob/master/entrypoint.sh) I was able to see that they're using `gosu oracle sqlplus` to connect to the database with elevated privileges, so I tried this in my environment and seems to fit perfectly to what you need:

```sh
docker exec -it oracle-12cR1-ee sh -c 'gosu oracle sqlplus "sys as sysdba"'
```

getting..

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sat Jun 29 00:33:12 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

and then being able to (for example):

```
SQL> SELECT USERNAME from SYS.ALL_USERS;
```

Enjoy! ;)

---

Edit:

Using just `sqlplus / as sysdba` also works as well, so it would be:

```sh
docker exec -it oracle-12cR1-ee sh -c 'gosu oracle sqlplus / as sysdba'
```